# Has anyone used Versions for OSX?

Tags: svn, macos, tortoisesvn

Has anyone used [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/) for OSX? I'm mainly wondering if it does everything [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) does and if you can use both with the same checkout repo?

**Edit:** The one issue I found is the diff viewer. The OSX developer FileMerger is just not that great. TortoiseSVN has got this right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Versions is a very good SVN client for OSX, it has all the features that TortoiseSVN has with a better and more pleasant graphic interface :)

I especially like the timeline view, it's very useful.

You can use it along Tortoise, but I don't know why you should need to, Tortoise is Windows-only.

Answer (score 3):

I tried it out 5-6 weeks ago and it seemed solid but didn't have all of TortoiseSVN's features, and the interface had some inconsistencies. It has a timeline which was very useful organization of the history.

I see they've reached version 1.0 in the last week and the changes seem to cover all the things that I thought were missing. It will be worthwhile to check it out.

Answer (score 3):

As Paul says, v1.0 is now out and feels much more complete. It even manages to look a bit slicker too!

It has all the features that I've been used to from TortoiseSVN before - except I haven't yet worked out if you can set svn -ignore from the GUI. It does respect it if it's been set, at least.

You can get the released version on 30 day trial, so why not check it out (pun intended) yourself? Personally I think it's well worth the small amount it costs.

Comment: svn ignore has been added to the 1.0 release: http://www.versionsapp.com/releasenotes

Comment: I have downloaded the trial, but it's quite likely I won't some feature that I'll need later.

Comment: Thanks David - I have to admit I haven't looked for it since the 1.0 release

Answer (score 1):

Yes I've been using Versions over the last two weeks, and it's nice enough to not make me need Tortoise for Mac, I feel its doing a good job covering the Niche, especially if you consider that Versions hasn't been around long compared to Tortoise.

However besides Versions I also strongly recommend you use [SCPlugin](http://scplugin.tigris.org/) it give you the right click context menu a la Tortoise, which is useful for quickly handling your sources.

Comment: I like the concept behind SCPlugin, but it has been quite inconsistent at properly badging icons in Finder, which is one feature that many TortoiseSVN users hope/expect to see.

Answer (score 0):

Another graphic svn client for osx is [Cornerstone](http://www.zennaware.com/cornerstone/).

I haven't tried it yet, but from the screenshots and the features looks promising.

Comment: Hmm, looks very similar to Versions. Unfortunately they both don't have diff viewers.

Comment: Versions integrates nicely with a number of diff viewers. I use FileMerge (part of the Xcode dev tools) and it worked great with Changes (http://connectedflow.com/changes/) when I tried it.